# Hillshade image blend that is not washed out (Earth Engine)

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, hillshade

I want to add hillshade to an image visualization in Earth Engine. I have done so by blending a semi-transparent image onto a hillshade layer. The desired appearance of terrain is added, but the image color is washed out. I can reduce transparency to increase original color fidelity, but then the terrain effect is less dramatic. How can I add hillshade to an image without dulling it? I've included code to demo my current semi-transparent image overlay method.

```
// Import an S2 surface reflectance image.
var s2 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED/20220726T185931_20220726T190831_T10TFT');

// Visualize the image as [R, G, B] = [SWIR1, NIR, Green]
var s2Vis = s2.visualize({bands: ['B11', 'B8', 'B3'], min: 0, max: 4200});
Map.setCenter(-120.9689, 47.5918, 11);
Map.addLayer(s2Vis, null, 's2Vis');

// Make a hillshade image from a DEM.
var hillshade = ee.Terrain.hillshade({
  input: ee.Image('NASA/NASADEM_HGT/001').select('elevation').multiply(1.1),
  azimuth: 150,
  elevation: 30
}).updateMask(s2.select(0).mask());

// Blend a 30% transparent copy of the S2 image over the hillshade image.
var s2VisConstHill = hillshade.blend(s2Vis.visualize({opacity: 0.70}));
Map.addLayer(s2VisConstHill, null, 's2VisConstHill');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "gee-blend" module for the Code Editor offers a series of common image blending functions (like those found in QGIS, ArcGIS Pro, Adobe Illustrator).

See: https://github.com/jessjaco/gee-blend

The `blend.multiply` mode is the same as the "hillshade-as-weighting-factor method" described in a different answer, but wrapped in a convenient function. Try other modes and further customize the effect by adjusting gamma and transparency as you usually would. Here is an example of `blend.multiply` building off the demo.

```js
// Import an S2 surface reflectance image.
var s2 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED/20220726T185931_20220726T190831_T10TFT');

// Visualize the image as [R, G, B] = [SWIR1, NIR, Green]
var s2Vis = s2.visualize({bands: ['B11', 'B8', 'B3'], min: 0, max: 4200});
Map.setCenter(-120.9689, 47.5918, 11);
Map.addLayer(s2Vis, null, 's2Vis');

// Make a hillshade image from a DEM.
var hillshade = ee.Terrain.hillshade({
  // Divide the DEM by 2 to flatten it a little, otherwise the terrain effect is
  // too exagerated - play around with how much you flatten it.
  input: ee.Image('NASA/NASADEM_HGT/001').select('elevation').divide(2),
  azimuth: 150,
  elevation: 30
});

// Load the blend module.
var blend = require('users/jja/public:blend.js');

// Use the `multiply` blend function to weight the image by hillshade. 
Map.addLayer(blend.multiply(s2Vis, hillshade), {min: 0, max: 0.7, gamma: 1.3});
```

Answer (score 3):

In a hillshade image, flat-ish areas appear grey. All of this grey is washing out the image in areas where there is not much topography. You can make a variable transparency hillshade layer that enhances regions with lots of topography and leaves regions that are flat-ish mostly unaltered. Here is an implementation that builds on the demo.

```
// Import an S2 surface reflectance image.
var s2 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED/20220726T185931_20220726T190831_T10TFT');

// Visualize the image as [R, G, B] = [SWIR1, NIR, Green]
var s2Vis = s2.visualize({bands: ['B11', 'B8', 'B3'], min: 0, max: 4200});
Map.setCenter(-120.9689, 47.5918, 11);
Map.addLayer(s2Vis, null, 's2Vis');

// Make a hillshade image from a DEM.
var hillshade = ee.Terrain.hillshade({
  input: ee.Image('NASA/NASADEM_HGT/001').select('elevation').multiply(1.1),
  azimuth: 150,
  elevation: 30
}).updateMask(s2.select(0).mask());


// ####### Hillshade w/ constant transparency #######

// Blend a 30% transparent copy of the S2 image over the hillshade image.
var s2VisConstHill = hillshade.blend(s2Vis.visualize({opacity: 0.70}));
Map.addLayer(s2VisConstHill, null, 's2VisConstHill');


// ####### Hillshade w/ variable transparency #######

// Define value and opacity ranges for low and high illumination regions.
var loIllum = {
  valRange: [0, 170],     // values you consider low illumination
  opacRange: [-200, 170]  // value range to stretch opacity [1,0]
};

var hiIllum = {
  valRange: [210, 255],  // values you consider high illumination
  opacRange: [210, 700]  // value range to stretch opacity [0,1]
};

// Create low and high illumination hillshade images with transparency
// gradient controlled by illumination; combine them and blend on top
// of the original image.
var loIllumHill = ee.Image(1).subtract(  // need to reverse the value order.
  hillshade.clamp(loIllum.valRange[0], loIllum.valRange[1])
  .unitScale(loIllum.opacRange[0], loIllum.opacRange[1]))
  .selfMask()
  .visualize({min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['000000']});

var hiIllumHill =
  hillshade.clamp(hiIllum.valRange[0], hiIllum.valRange[1])
  .unitScale(hiIllum.opacRange[0], hiIllum.opacRange[1])
  .selfMask()
  .visualize({min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['FFFFFF']});

var s2VisVariHill = s2Vis.blend(loIllumHill.blend(hiIllumHill));
Map.addLayer(s2VisVariHill, null, 's2VisVariHill');
```

[Code Editor link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/437efed424aa08f3e5f73cbc8d28213c)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the hillshade layer as a weighting factor to make low-illumination pixels darker by dividing the hillshade layer by 255 to get it into range [0,1] and then multiply it by the RGB visualization image. When visualizing an 8-bit RGB image, the typical stretch is [0,255], but after weighting the image, the majority of the values will be reduced, so you need to adjust the `max` value lower. Another factor to play around with is DEM exaggeration: to make the hillshade more dramatic, multiple the DEM by e.g., 2 and to soften the hillshade, divide by 2. This method can saturate high illumination regions if the `max` visualization parameter is set too low. Here is an example that builds off the initial demo.

```js
// Import an S2 surface reflectance image.
var s2 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED/20220726T185931_20220726T190831_T10TFT');

// Visualize the image as [R, G, B] = [SWIR1, NIR, Green]
var s2Vis = s2.visualize({bands: ['B11', 'B8', 'B3'], min: 0, max: 4200});
Map.setCenter(-120.9689, 47.5918, 11);
Map.addLayer(s2Vis, null, 's2Vis');

// Make a hillshade image from a DEM.
var hillshade = ee.Terrain.hillshade({
  // Divide the DEM by 2 to flatten it a little, otherwise the terrain effect is
  // too exagerated - play around with how much you flatten it.
  input: ee.Image('NASA/NASADEM_HGT/001').select('elevation').divide(2),
  azimuth: 150,
  elevation: 30
})
// Divide hillshade by 255 to get range [0,1] for weighting the RGB viz image.
.divide(255);

// Multiply the RGB image by the hillshade weight - low illumination pixels are
// made darker across all three bands of the RGB image.
var s2VisHill = s2Vis.multiply(hillshade);

// When visualizing the hillshade-weighted RGB image, adjust the max
// (255 for 8-bit RGB images) to a lower value because most of the image
// has been darkened, lowering the max value will brighten it up again -
// you'll maybe want to play around with the new max value.
Map.addLayer(s2VisHill, {min: 0, max: 160}, 's2VisHill');
```

[Code Editor link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ee844298d64f8866c2d59973fc119d09)

[image]